# scrolling id# on the same page does not work correctly when jquery page fading on load is included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problems with the id# linking on the same page when I include a jquery page fade out and fade in. When I just had the plain html it worked fine.

**To Clarify:** I have a section on the same and have a link in the nav area at the top that scrolls down to the lower half of the page. When the jquery code is included either as a separate js file or part of the html page that link scrolls down ( which I want to do) but it also fades out which I don't want it to do.

Hears the jquery fade code:

```
jQuery('body').css('display','none');
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('body').fadeIn();
jQuery('a').on('click',function(event){
var thetarget = this.getAttribute('target')
if (thetarget != "_blank"){
var thehref = this.getAttribute('href')
event.preventDefault();
jQuery('body').fadeOut(function(){
window.location = thehref
});
}
});
});
setTimeout(function(){
jQuery('fade').fadeIn();
},1000)
```

Html code thats not working

```
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" 
href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
```

Am I targeting the wrong element. I also tried to make change to no avail.

Need help please!

Answer (score 0):

**Tip:** Do not bind the event listener **(onclick)** to all `<a></a>` tags. Just bind it to a single one using it's specific ID or class name!

---

**So I've edited this line**:

```
jQuery('a').on('click', function(event)
```

to

```
jQuery('#about').on('click', function(event)
```

and added the **ID="about" tag** to your link.

---

```js
jQuery('body').css('display', 'none');
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('body').fadeIn();
  jQuery('#about').on('click', function(event) {
    var thetarget = this.getAttribute('target')
    if (thetarget != "_blank") {
      var thehref = this.getAttribute('href')
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery('body').fadeOut(function() {
        window.location = thehref
      });
    }
  });
});
setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery('fade').fadeIn();
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a id="about" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="https://google.com">About</a>
</li>
```

If you do not want this result, an edit would help your question. Because at least you have completely confused me. Just let me know what your problem is. :)

Comment: To Clarify: On the same page I have a link in the navigation that scrolls down to the lower half of the page.                                    
                                                                                                      When the jquery code is included either as a separate js file or part of the html page that link scrolls down ( which I want to do) but it also fades out which I don't want it to do.

Comment: What I don't want it to do is fade out after the Portfolio link scrolls down to the lower half of the page

Comment: So you just want to run the animation after clicking the "about" link? And disable this animation clicking the portfolio href? @RajivNarayanan

Comment: yes. that is correct. Thank you for you help. Still having the problem. I'm still quite new to js and jquery

Comment: Did you have a look on my edit? Do not bind the event listener **(onclick)** to all `<a></a>` tags. Just bind it to a single one using it's specific ID or class-name @RajivNarayanan